# Trasition border-bottom?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to fade in `border-bottom` and I can't quite seem to get it to work. Here's what I've tried:

```
#navBar a:hover {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        }
```

It just keeps appearing with no transition. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: works for me (see http://jsfiddle.net/j6KLu/) using FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to transition by adding a border, which does not work.  You can, however, have the color of the border transition from `transparent` to `#FFF`:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="navBar">
    <a>Link</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#navBar a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#navBar a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6KLu/2/)</kbd>

Comment: What if I wanted to faded the border out once unhovered?

Comment: It does fade out once unhovered.  If you try hovering over the example from the Fiddle, it will fade out, but make sure that you are using the fiddle from my most recent answer: http://jsfiddle.net/j6KLu/2/

Comment: Ah, I must've done something wrong. I fixed it though. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  I think you were just using the fiddle from the answer that I posted before editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go from no border to white you should still write default attribute because transition won't do this for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmUAw/3/

```
#navBar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

And after that you can change it to white with transition

```
#navBar a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants this transition to appear when hovered, at least I can't read anything else.

Comment: I see. I guess it's time to go to sleep. Actually your example works strange also, your transition starts with black to white. I guess the best way to do this is http://jsfiddle.net/ZmUAw/1/, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I didn't realize it wasn't on purpose.  Have a good day.